# BabylonJs React Project - Resize Window

Tags: reactjs, resize, babylonjs

Doing the BabylonJs Reactjs tutorial in React using Hooks (functional components) instead of classes and I'm running into issue resizing the window.

```
// This code block cannot be added in a component...
  onResizeWindow = () => {
    if (this.engine) {
      this.engine.resize();
    }
  };

... so I rewrote it to 
const onResizeWindow = props => {
    if (props.engine) {
      props.engine.resize();
    }
  };

... Then added the listener to the engine hook like below

 useEffect(() => {
    let engine = new BABYLON.Engine(
      canvas,
      true,
      props.engineOptions,
      props.adaptToDeviceRatio
    );

    let scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);

    if (typeof props.onSceneMount === "function") {
      props.onSceneMount({
        scene,
        engine,
        canvas
      });
    } else {
      console.error("onSceneMount function not available");
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", onResizeWindow(props));
  });
```

This is not working. I've tried a few variations of the above code, but it is not resizing the screen appropriately. Has anyone else faced this issue? I looked around for others who have asked this question and could not find.

Comment: No one using BabylonJS along with functional style in ReactJS?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is not too late to answer this question. But I do encounter the same issue couple times. and here is my solution.

We need two parts.

First, in the functional component.

```
 <div id="canvasWrapper">
    <SceneComponent antialias onSceneReady={onSceneReady} observeCanvasResize adaptToDeviceRatio onRender={onRender} id="my-canvas" />
 </div>
```

We need the **adaptToDeviceRatio** and **observeCanvasResize** attrribute.

Second,

For the CSS. we also need to add these to make sure it is filling the full window.

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#canvasWrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
canvas{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #000000;
  display: block;
}
```

By applying these. You should be able to have the correct resize behaviour as expected.